# Custom HTML template with material not working in angular-formly

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I have a field in formly and want to customise the field using my own HTML. The field looks like this:

```
 {
   className: 'rememberMeField',
   key: 'rememberMe',
   template: '<mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>',
 },
```

The issue is when the field is rendered to the page the mat-checkbox selector is changed to a plain div - taking away all of the material-ui functionality. How can I fix this?

Comment: I dont think you can pass custom html with angular-formly

Comment: template - string -> Can be set instead of type to render custom html content. VIA: https://formly.dev/guide/properties-options

Comment: that should be raw html rather than another angular component